# Loading a nib file inside a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I'm experimenting on how to load nib files to a `UIViewController`.

I have created a separate nib file called **Email**. First I noticed that when the view controller is loaded, the `initWithNibName` method isn't getting called. So I called it from the `viewDidLoad` method manually like this,

```
[self initWithNibName:@"Email" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

It did not work. Also I got a warning saying *Expression result unused*.

And I searched on the internet and came across [this](http://www.indelible.org/ink/nib-loading/) article and implemented the `loadView` method as described like so,

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Email" bundle:nil];
    [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
}
```

The method gets called but still the view controller is empty!

Can anybody tell me what I'm overlooking here and how this can be done?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

First off, thanks for all the responses. However **voromax** and **svena**'s answers suggest that I should remove segues and load nibs automatically which I'm not very fond of. Anil's answer works find and now I have one last hurdle to jump.

I have multiple nib files. Depending on the user's selection, it should load a specific nib. So what I tried was, put all the nibs inside the array like so,

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    NSArray *nibs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Facsimile" owner:self options:nil],
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Email" owner:self options:nil],
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Memorandum" owner:self options:nil],
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProjectMemo" owner:self options:nil], nil];


    self.view = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

and access it using its index like this `self.view = [nibs objectAtIndex:1];`. But it throws an error *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd56fd20'*

Why is this error coming up? If its not possible, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks again. And sorry for kinda dragging this out a bit.

Comment: You still did not mention the storyboards and custom logic in your question, not everybody will read all the comments... See the updated answer

Answer (score 9):

Use the below code to load a view from the nib and use as the view controller's view

```
- (void)loadView
{ 
[super loadView];

NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"test" owner:self options:nil];
self.view = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

**Edit**

Load a single nib according to the user selection. See loading of a single nib

```
    NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"test" owner:self options:nil];
```

will returns an array of objects. From your updated question I can see you are storing these arrays into another array. Now your nib array is an array of 'array' objects.

```
 self.view = [[nibs objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
```

will work.

But it is not good, load a single nib according to the user choise

Comment: Thanks for the response. This method works and I have a side question. I have multiple nib files. Depending on the user's selection, it should load a specific nib. So what I tried was, put all the nibs inside the array like [this](http://pastebin.com/rcpHTTSY) and access it using its index liek this `self.view = [nibs objectAtIndex:1];`. But it throws an error _Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd56fd20'_ Am I missing something or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: Can you post your code along with the question? I cant access that page. Actually the nib array returns by the __loadNib__ contains not only view s, it contains all the controls in your nib(buttons/ label..) objectAtIndex[0] will be the top level object(most probably a view if you have single view per nib). With out seeing your code i cant say exact problem

Comment: @Isuru Good solution to get the view from the nib. But what will happen to the subviews bindings?

Comment: @voromax If you are loading nib to get view, the view should be a custom view. You have to made binding to the custom class not to the files owner(view controller). Then communication b/w view and controller use delegate. This is a solution used when a view controller can have more than one view to handle, view may be vary depending on some condition(iphone/ipad).I will not prefer this method since it is complicated. Otherwise separate view controller for each view is better.  But the OP really wants this he can go with this solution

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to load a nib for the view controller from within the methods of that view controller.

If you want to instantiate a view controller from nib, you do that from outside of that view controller, usually the view controller that presents it.

If you are looking for a hook inside presented view controller that would already have the outlet connections set up, overriding `-awakeFromNib` is a popular choice. `-viewDidLoad` is another.

Update #1

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
   if ( /*do your segue identification stuff*/ ) {
      UIViewController *myViewController = /*init your view controller here*/
      UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
      [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
      return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: There's a `UITableViewController` as the previous view controller so I tried loading the nib when instantiating it just before the segue happens. `NewMailViewController *newMailVC = [[NewMailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Email" bundle:nil];
        newMailVC = [segue destinationViewController];` But it didn't work.

Comment: From your comment I conclude you are using storyboards. Storyboards instantiate your view controllers for you and you don't load those nibs yourself. Is there a reason why you would like to go back to loading from nib from using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Storyboards. Sorry I should have mentioned that in the question. The scenario is like this. I'm creating a custom mail app and there are multiple mail types. For each mail type, the UI is different. So what I did was, create a separate nib for each mail type, have a `UITableViewController` to list the mail types and when it segues, depending on the user's selection it loads the specific nib file to a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Perhaps not the "prettiest" solution, but yes, you will have to cancel the segue (as @voromax suggested) and then instantiate from nib manually. But not only instantiate, but also push it into navigation stack or present it. Init in itself is not enough,

Comment: @Isuru in your case it is better to create all view controllers in one storyboard, skip the hard segue binding and use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method of your segue instance to get the appropriate view controller  and present it manually

Comment: @svena +1 for the desirable storyboard consistency

Answer (score 1):

You should use the nib file to instantiate the view controller itself i. e.

```
UIViewController *ctrl = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Email" bundle:nil];
```

After that you can present this controller

**Update**

In case if you need to select which view controller should be loaded by the application logic it is better to create all view controllers in one storyboard, skip the hard segue binding and use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method of your storyboard instance to get the appropriate view controller and present it manually. I assume that your table view controller is already in navigation controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    if (APPROPRIATE_INDEX_PATH) {
        UIViewController *ctrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a `UITableViewController` as the previous view controller so I tried loading the nib when instantiating it just before the segue happens. `NewMailViewController *newMailVC = [[NewMailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Email" bundle:nil];
        newMailVC = [segue destinationViewController];` But it didn't work.

Comment: You could cancel this segue by `– shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` returning NO and load your controller manually